# How to implement this complex RecyclerView UI design in Android?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-recyclerview

How can i implement the following UI design in Android?

The data is retrieved from API so each event is an item and also the Big red card is also an item. The problem here is the background, it should scroll with the items and the items should be positioned on the yellow line. I thought of ItemDecoration for item offset and a simple path to draw, but i never used ItemDecoration, and from this UI it seems that the background would be an Image.

Is there any way to implement this?

There is an application called [image: Chineasy], which has a similar design, but in horizontal scrolling. It has a long horizontal scroll with background image which seems like fragmented images stuck together when scrolling.

So please can any one help me get an idea of how this can be achieved?

[image: UI Design]